# CollectionViewで画像が表示されない

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

下記のようにコードを書いたのですが、`CollectionView`のセルに画像が表示されません。コードのどこが間違っているのでしょうか？ちなみに`Storyboard`のセルの`identifier`と`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`は一致しています。どなたか分かる方、教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSArray *datas;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    datas = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return datas.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 1];
    imageView.image = datas[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

プロトコルUICollectionViewDelegateと、とりわけUICollectionViewDataSourceを、ViewControllerクラスに組みこんでください。

### Storyboardにおいて：

Prototype Cellに、UIImageViewのインスタンスを配置し、そのインスタンスのtagを、1にしていますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。UICollectionViewDelegateとUICollectionViewDataSourceをViewControllerに組み込んだのですが画像は表示されませんでした。。。

Comment: プログラム上の誤りは、その1点だけです。あなたの書いたプログラムは、プログラムだけで完結していないことは、おわかりになってますね？Storyboard上の編集と組み合わせることで、初めて動くプログラムであることは、おわかりですね？たとえば、delegateと、dataSourceの指定は、プログラムで行っていないので、Storyboardで行うことは、おわかりになってますね？では、つぎは、Storyboardの編集に、欠け、誤りがないか、ご確認ください。

Comment: Storyboardを見たのですが、identifierを指定しており、delegateとdatasourceも紐付けあり、tagも1としています。それで試しにcellForItemAtIndexPath内でcell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];としてみると、緑色のセルが画面に現れました。ということはStoryboardの設定はできており、コード側の問題となってくるのでしょうか？

Comment: なんのタグを1にしているのですか？Storyboardの編集に間違いがないのなら、プログラムに問題はありませんから、画像ファイルの読み込みの問題でしょうね。

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath内で[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 1]としているので、Storyboardのセルのtagも1にしています。画像ファイルの読み込みを一度確認してみます。

Comment: 回答を増補しました。セルのtagをいじっても、意味ありませんよ。

Comment: すみません、まさにImageViewをセルに置いていなかったことが原因でした。大変助かりました！本当にありがとうございます。